# Problem with Apache Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, java

I have a little problem with Tomcat.

I'm using `Eclipse Helios` to luanch some `Servlets`, and I've installed Tomcat as a service on my Windows 7, but when I Run he give me an error Tomcat is already running, and when I stop the Tomcat service the compliation goes well but I get en error : The ressource is not found.

Is there any way to use `Tomcat 6` without installing it as a service; if yes can you give any tutorials, qo I can my `Servlets` or `JSP pages` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to develop with JSP/Servlets, you don't need to install Tomcat as Windows service at all. That's only interesting for production server machines running Windows which needs the server to be started on machine's startup without the need for user login.

Uninstall everything and go back to the Tomcat download page and download the zip file instead of the service exe file. Once downloaded, just extract the zip, recreate the server in Eclipse, specify the extracted zip folder as server location and manage it from there. That's it. No nasty exe files needed.

At the bottom of [our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) you can find a lot of tutorials. Among others the Coreservlets tutorials covers the Eclipse+Tomcat combo.

Comment: I did that, but when I start Tomcat and try to access to http://localhost:8080 I get that  error saying ressource is not found.

Comment: Tomcat is running fine, but just nothing has been deployed to the ROOT by Eclipse. If you expect to see the Tomcat default homepage for some reason (I don't see how that's useful), you'd need to configure Eclipse to entirely take over Tomcat instead of only using its engine for Eclipse projects. Doubleclick the server entry in Eclipse, head to *Server Location* section and click the *Use Tomcat installation* option.

Comment: If you want to run your own project, you'd need to navigate to the project's URL instead of the Tomcat root. Eclipse defaults to the project name, such as `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this may be the error. Whenever you install Tomcat , it starts automatically and when you make a server and run it again it Eclipse this error generates.

Go to control Panel --> services and stop the tom cat manually from there.

Then whenever you start it from eclipse the port you will found is empty so no error will be generated..